# The Diversity Visa Process

Tags: usa, visa, application-status

> I have friend of mine who received notification through the Electronic Diversity Visa (E-DV) website that he has been selected for further processing in the Diversity Immigrant Visa ( **DV-2017** ) Program so i need to Submit him for a Visa Application (Submit his Immigrant Visa and Alien Registration Application )

- for that i checked the website of https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/immigrate/diversity-visa/if-you-are-selected/submit-your-ds-260-online-application.html

> they said that : After submitting the Form **DS-260 online**, print
>   the confirmation page. You must bring the confirmation page to your
>   visa interview. "

so i went there https://ceac.state.gov/ceac/ but i found

. **NONIMMIGRANT**
:

1. DS-160, Online Nonimmigrant Visa Application
2. DS-1648, Online A, G, or NATO Application
3. Check My Visa Application Status
   :

. **IMMIGRANT**:

4. DS-261, Online Choice of Address and AgentFee Payment
5. DS-260, Online Immigrant Visa and Alien Registration Application
6. Check My Visa Application Status

My question i don't know what i choice to submit him in **DS-260 online** knowing that he is a single he had master's degree in mathematics and living in morroco

Comment: I think you should find someone who's better versed in English to help you understand. Messing this up will cause your friend the chance. Your question is really hard to read, and even harder to understand.

Comment: Unlike @littleadv, I did not have too much trouble understanding your question, but I agree with his conclusion. If you are unsure which link to choose on the ceac.state.gov page, the risk of failure without additional help is very high. I believe he meant to say that messing up will *cost* your friend the chance, and that is true. I know of several cases where visa applications were denied because the applications were poorly prepared. It seems unfair, but that's how it is.

Comment: yes i see that's way i sent email to KCCDV@state.gov for ask about more information. thanks for your care .

Answer (score 3):

> My question i don't know what i choice to submit him in DS-260 online
>   knowing that he is a single he had master's degree in mathematics and
>   living in morroco

I am not sure what you are actually asking for.

You use option 5, "DS-260, Online Immigrant Visa and Alien Registration Application", login using his case number and fill out the form. Since I don't have his case number I have no idea what the form looks like.

I agree with the others who suggested to have either an experienced immigration lawer or at least someone with a very good understanding of English (as well as about the immigration/green card process) to fill out the application.

As an example. where they ask about country of residence, put Morrocco. If he was born in another country, put that country in "country of birth", etc. If you don't understand the difference between "country of birth", "country of citizenship" and "country of residency", you are probably going to mess up, and he might be denied his green card.

Comment: it's okay i know the differences also i understand english. anyway thank you